# Extract JSON-Key from incoming stream

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I am currently working on an endpoint for the Postmark service. Postmark sends received E-Mails as JSON and put the attachments as Base64 into an "Attachment"-Array.
My question is now if it is possible to use akka streams to extract the Attachments while receiving them and "do my things" with it?"
In details: I wanna slice the Attachments into chunks, hash them while they come in to store the chunks in my database.
The rest of the incoming JSON can be processed (without) the attachments afterwards.
The reason I wanna do this, is to use as little memory as possible becuase the attachment sizes can go up to 100MB and the hashing of such big files can use a lot of processing power at once.
I hope to save memory and to much cpu load if I process the attachments in chunks.

If you know a better way to achieve this I am open for any suggestion! :)

Comment: Would you like the full coded solution?

Comment: No I wanna code and learn it myself. If you just tell me that its possible and I am on the right track that's okay. If you have an y details on the way even better. :)

Comment: Yes, you can do it via Akka Streams if you want to process in chunks. Also look into Akka Stream fan-out so that given one input you can fan out into other streams that do stuff concurrently.

Comment: **Thanks!** I am using Play Framework and I am either using **this** in a Bodyparser or I am thinking about to use akka http and streams just for this purpose and file uploads. Thanks for your help!